# Does HAWQ reuse QE processes after a query finished?

Tags: executor, hawq

Query Executor processes are created on segments to do query execution. When I doing a query, I can see the working QEs. But when the query is finished, they are still alive with idle state. Does HAWQ reuse QE processes after a query finished?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, HAWQ QE Process is kept in session level. If you have already finished a query but with session alive, the next query you sent through the same session will reuse the already started QEs.

There are two phenomenons:
1) The catched QE process number is less than the QEs needed for the new query on the same host. Under this case, HAWQ will reuse the catched QEs, and also start new QEs for the not-enough number.
2) The catched QE process number is more than the QEs needed for the new query on the same host. Under this case, HAWQ will choose some QEs inside of these catched QEs. You'll see some QEs still idle.

The number of QEs needed is decided by resource manager.

Moveover, if you run the "SET" command, if there are catched QEs on the segment hosts, all the QEs will be reused. But if there are no catched QEs, the "SET" command will not start any QEs in segment.

Answer (score 1):

The cache of QEs in HAWQ is designed for two purpose:

1. Reuse the QEs between consecutive queries so as to avoid forking them every time we run a query, and thus improve query performance, especially for small query.
2. Debug in feature development and bug fix.

The QEs of current query is released if current session is closed or they are idle after gp_vmem_idle_resource_timeout ms. It is 10 minutes in debug build, and 18 seconds in release build by default. You may refer to [guc.c](https://github.com/apache/incubator-hawq/blob/master/src/backend/utils/misc/guc.c) for details:

```
{
    {"gp_vmem_idle_resource_timeout", PGC_USERSET, CLIENT_CONN_OTHER,
        gettext_noop("Sets the time a session can be idle (in milliseconds) before we release gangs on the segment DBs to free resources."),
        gettext_noop("A value of 0 turns off the timeout."),
        GUC_UNIT_MS | GUC_GPDB_ADDOPT
    },
    &IdleSessionGangTimeout,

#ifdef USE_ASSERT_CHECKING
    600000, 0, INT_MAX, NULL, NULL /* 10 minutes by default on debug builds.*/
#else
    18000, 0, INT_MAX, NULL, NULL
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If in an interval, there comes another query, QEs can be reused. If this interval timeout, QEs quit.

Comment: How long is the interval set by default? Can this interval be set by user?

Answer (score 0):

Moreover session quit will quit all the forked QEs no matter the interval is.

Answer (score 0):

The interval GUC is gp_vmem_idle_resource_timeout, you can set it in your session.